# encrypt and decrypt in php not working

Tags: php, encryption

Original URL

```
/category.php?id=28
```

After encryptiong

```
/category.php?id=DyAtftpy3cg4RNtJWT51vFlU5fMVuN+bvaTC365XYkU=

function encryptIt( $q ) {
    $cryptKey  = 'qJB0rGtIn5UB1xG03efyCp';
    $qEncoded      = base64_encode( mcrypt_encrypt( MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5( $cryptKey ), $q, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5( md5( $cryptKey ) ) ) );
    return $qEncoded;
}
```

**decrypt**

```
decryptIt($_REQUEST['id']);
```

used function

```
function decryptIt( $q ) {
    $cryptKey  = 'qJB0rGtIn5UB1xG03efyCp';
    $qDecoded      = rtrim( mcrypt_decrypt( MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5( $cryptKey ), base64_decode( $q ), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5( md5( $cryptKey ) ) ), "\0");
    return $qDecoded;
}
```

But it returns `���.�_��JC �\Y|{�[=4�V!�o$��`

Comment: What is that meant to do? This would not protect anyone from anything. You sure thought through this?

Comment: Using a fixed IV defeats the purpose of CBC and substantially reduces your security.

Comment: Now that your secret key is not secret anymore, the encryption is useless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
base64_encode( mcrypt_encrypt( MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5( $cryptKey ),
    $q, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5( md5( $cryptKey ) ) ) );
```

should be

```
base64_encode( mcrypt_encrypt( MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5( $cryptKey ),
    $var, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5( md5( $cryptKey ) ) ) );
```

**What's `$q`? Should it not be `$var`?** (in `encryptIt`)

**WORKS FOR ME**:

```
function decryptIt($data, $key) {
    $key = md5($key);
    $data = base64_decode($data);
    $decrypted = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256,
        $key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5($key));
    $decrypted = rtrim($decrypted, "\0");
    return $decrypted;
}
function encryptIt($data, $key) {
    $key = md5($key);
    $encrypted = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256,
        $key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5($key));
    $encrypted = base64_encode($encrypted);
    return $encrypted;
}
// Testing
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
$data = 'testing';
$key = 'qJB0rGtIn5UB1xG03efyCp';
$encrypted = encryptIt($data, $key);
// Added your own data here (IT WORKS)
$encrypted = 'DyAtftpy3cg4RNtJWT51vFlU5fMVuN+bvaTC365XYkU=';
echo 'Encrypted: ', $encrypted, '<br>', PHP_EOL;
$decrypted = decryptIt($encrypted, $key);
echo 'Decrypted: ', $decrypted, '<br>', PHP_EOL;
```

^ **Don't know what you're doing wrong but I did something:** *I stopped the imbricated instruction madness.* Assigned variables to each and made the code clear, easy to follow and... functional... I think :)

**PS**: *It's nice to have one-liners but it will torment you if you have bugs in the 1-liners.*

Comment: i used like this function encryptIt( $q ) in mycode...wrongly copied in here

Comment: @Dhamu Will check your code now. I've seen that instantly looking at it. Will update the response if I find the issue.

Comment: @Dhamu Updated the answer. Works for me. Not sure what you did wrong but use this code and see if it works.

Comment: In same page encryption working good, but while pass to another page i can't get the decryption... its shows ���.�_��JC �\Y|{�[=4�V!�o$�

Comment: @Dhamu Added your own `$encrypted` data and it decrypts to 28. It can't fail if your rest of the code is correct. So if you use the `$_GET['id']` when decrypting, it can't fail.

Comment: i used $_GET['id'] but still it returns ���.�_��JC �\Y|{�[=4�V!�o$�

Answer (score 1):

Okay, my last post is deleted...

I saw it was working on cli but not through apache.

This was the solution for me:

```
decryptit(htmlentities($_GET['i'],ENT_QUOTES | ENT_IGNORE, "UTF-8"));
```

By the way, I use the code from php manual now.

Regards